# convert varchar2 value to decimal in oracle VIEW

Tags: oracle, view, plsql

i need to select a varchar2 value '>45%' (from table ABC, column name XYZ) as decimal, like select statement should return 0.45. 
How to achieve this? i am not getting how to do this with regular_expression, or by Trimming and converting to number.

Comment: select to_number(replace(replace('>45%', '>', ''), '%', ''))/100 from dual; - trythat

Comment: Why do you need this? Also, if the condition is >45%, why should the select statement return 0.45? Shouldn't it return all the values that are STRICTLY GREATER THAN 0.45?

Comment: its working for that specific value, but i need to do this for that column values. for example: 
select regexp_replace('column_name', '\>|\%', '') / 100
    from 'table_name'



, OR


select 'column_name' 
    from 'table_name'
    where regexp_replace('column_name', '\>|\%', '') / 100


but its returning invalid number error. Possible patterns of columns values may include '>45%', '<60%', etc

Comment: Can it also be '>0' or '<1' etc.? Again, **why do you need this**? Let me guess: you have conditions that should be used in a WHERE clause, saved as VARCHAR2 in some table. That is such a dumb thing to do, it deserves no help. Are you re-writing the Oracle parser from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Removes characters `>` and `%` and devide the result by 100. the character string is converted automatically to number

```
select regexp_replace('>45%', '\>|\%', '') / 100 from dual
```

Another approach: Remove all non-number characters:

```
select regexp_replace('>45%', '[^0-9]', '')/100 from dual
```

Comment: How will this distinguish between > and < ? (Assuming that matters of course; I really don't understand what the OP may be using this for.)

Comment: @mathguy It is not requested to distinguish between `<` and `>`.

Comment: @MK- come on! Accept this answer already, can't get much better than that.

Comment: its working for that specific value, but i need to do this for that column values. for example: 
select regexp_replace('column_name', '\>|\%', '') / 100
    from 'table_name'



, OR


select 'column_name' 
    from 'table_name'
    where regexp_replace('column_name', '\>|\%', '') / 100


but its returning invalid number error. Possible patterns of columns values may include '>45%', '<60%', etc